# No output on Travis CI for system tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing, travis-ci, system-testing

I have some weird behavior on a Rails 6.0.4 application when running system tests: when running `rails test:system` on my machine I correctly see which error is failing, but in Travis I only see the following, without any hint of which error failed:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.8 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:34339
Use Ctrl-C to stop
The command "bundle exec rails test:system" exited with 1.
```

The only thing that pops on my mind is the parallelization, but I tried with and without the `parallelize` statement in `test_helper.rb` and it didn't change much, unfortunately.

This is the content of .travis.yml:

```
language: ruby
cache: bundler

before_install:
  - yes | gem update --system
  - gem install bundler

env:
  global:
    # CodeClimate : INI
    - COVERAGE=true
    - secure: #..................
    # CodeClimate : END

rvm:
  - 2.6.6

services:
  - mysql
  - mongodb

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - mysql-5.7-bionic
    packages:
      - mysql-server

dist: bionic

sudo: required

before_install:
  - yes | gem update --system
  - gem install bundler

before_script:
  # needed for system testing
  - sudo -- sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/run/puma/ && chown travis /var/run/puma/'
  - sudo -- sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/log/puma/ && chown travis /var/log/puma/'
  - sudo mysql_upgrade
  - sudo service mysql restart
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load

  # CodeClimate : INI
  - curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 > ./cc-test-reporter
  - chmod +x ./cc-test-reporter
  - ./cc-test-reporter before-build
  # CodeClimate : END

script:
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" != "false" ]; then bundle exec rails checks:all; fi
  - bundle exec rails test
  - bundle exec rails test:system

after_script:
  # CodeClimate : INI
  - ./cc-test-reporter after-build --exit-code $TRAVIS_TEST_RESULT
  # CodeClimate : END

notifications:
  email:
    - developers@company.com
```

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding following to .travis.yml:

```
addons:
  chrome: stable
```